# MOSFET for 3.3v MCU

Tags: transistors, mosfet, 3.3v, esp32

I'm building a custom board with ESP32-WROOM-32E that can supply 3.3v trough the GPIO. I need to power a screen using 3.3v power. I'm looking for a way to power off the backlight using the GPIO pins and thought of a MOSFET as the board can be battery powered and is the most efficient switch, compared to a bipolar transistor. My question is how can I use a MOSFET if the source is 3.3v and the gate when on high is 3.3v? How could this work?

I will assemble my board using JLCPCB mount service and I wanted to know what MOSFET should I be looking for and if you can suggest something in the JLCPCB library.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use a low-side switch, so the source is at 0V, and a logic-level FET.

Comment: Cloud you explain further?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain further. Use an N-channel FET with source connected to 0V and drain connected to the low side of your load. Pick a FET with a low RDSon rated at 3.3 V or below, and remember that the threshold voltage is not where the FET is fully on.

Comment: The problem is that there is not a low side of the load. Is a power line to a module, an ILI9341. So I necessarily need to put the switch on the powerline before the screen LED pin

Comment: There is definitely a low side or it wouldn't work.

Comment: There is only a ground but it is for the whole screen, not the pin I want to interrupt

Comment: That's unusual, the backlight is usually separate from the rest of the screen, but in that case the simplest option is probably a solid-state relay.

Comment: Have you tried turning the backlight on and off via the ILI9341's relevant commands?  If the ILI9341 is not controlling the backlight, then you may actually be able to get at the ground side.  You could use a PFET; but also beware that if you de-power the LCD module entirely, you'll need to first take all I/O lines running to it low, as it is not permitted to have I/O voltages outside the range of supply voltages.

Comment: In terms of this site, its important to be aware that part selection questions (eg "shopping questions") are prohibited.  As are questions about *undocumented products*.  This question is well on its way to being closed, and for it to survive you need to give actual engineering information about the LCD module and show full details of the proposed connections to your processor.